# returning a valid dataset using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, data-access-layer, bll

I keep getting an error when I select a value from my drop down.

`**The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.**`

It looks like my dataset is returning as empty.

I want to stick to the 3 tier structure.

How do i return a valid dataset using my code?

**DAL**

```
public static DataTable GetCustomer(collection b)
{
    {
        DataTable table;
        try
        {
            string returnValue = string.Empty;
            DB = Connect();
            DBCommand = connection.Procedure("getCustomer");
            DB.AddInParameter(DBCommand, "@CustomerRef", DbType.String, b.CustomerRef1);

            DbDataReader reader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();
            table = new DataTable();
            table.Load(reader);
            return table;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }

    }

}
```

**BLL**

Looks like I have some redundant code below. I would like to utilize my connection class below:

```
   public DataSet returnCustomer(collection b)
   {
       try
       {
           SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
           DataSet table = new DataSet();

           adapt.Fill(table, "table");
           return table;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
   }
```

**Connection Class**

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common;
using Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class connection
    {
        const string StrConnection = "CustomerHelperConnectionString";
        internal static Database DB;
        public static DbCommand DBCommand;
        public static Database Connect()
        {

            try
            {
                DB = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(StrConnection);
                return DB;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
        public static DbCommand Procedure(string procedure)
        {

            try
            {
                DBCommand = DB.GetStoredProcCommand(procedure);
                return DBCommand;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PL**

```
protected void ddl_Customers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DAL.collection cobj = new collection();
    BLL.business bobj = new business();

    string selectedValue = ddl_Customers.SelectedValue.ToString();

        //populate the text boxes
        txtCustomerRef.Text = bobj.returnCustomer(cobj).Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: In `returnCustomer` method, your dataadapter does not have any command in it. So, it is empty. There is nothing to fill from it.

Comment: Added connection class*

Comment: I think, BLL code is missing something, not doing anything, I meant, you need to have some command object to fill that or query DAL , get some value, apply filter based on business logic, then return object and if you need `CustomerRef1` only in `GetCustomer` you can pass `string` directly.

Comment: i need to eventually get customer name, customer address etc etc...

Comment: If you can show me and answer that would be good.. I have struggled with this all day and night :(

Comment: I am confused here, you get customer info by sending customer_ref_id and then you are trying to show customer ref in `txtCustomerRef` ? Is that intended? My assumption, `ddl_Customers` will get you selected `CustomerRef` and then you hit DB to get all details and display in individual `textbox` ?

Comment: Yes your assumption is correct.. Select CustID from drop down and then textboxes get populated. I need to pass custID into SP as that will return results just for that customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your DAL code like this:

```
public static DataTable GetCustomer(collection b)
{
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            string returnValue = string.Empty;
            DB = Connect();
            DBCommand = connection.Procedure("getCustomer");
            DB.AddInParameter(DBCommand, "@CustomerRef", DbType.String, b.CustomerRef1);

            SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(DBCommand);
            adptr.Fill(table);
            return table;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
}
```

and now your BAL like this,

```
public DataSet returnCustomer(collection b)
   {
       try
       {
           DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
           _ds.Tables.Add(DAL.GetCustomer(b));
           return _ds;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
   }
```

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Common.DbCommand' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.SqlDataAdapter(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I am open to your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

As per my assumption mentioned in comments to OP's question, you need to following.

Change DAL to have this `public static DataTable GetCustomer(string customer_ref)` and use this `DB.AddInParameter(DBCommand, "@CustomerRef", DbType.String, customer_ref);`

I see there is no work done in BAL, so I am skipping usage of that.

Instead of using BLL object in `bobj` use one of DAL instance as this has `GetCustomer` and has some work to fetch info from DB.

So assuming `bobj` is an instance of DAL, next, change PL, like this - `txtCustomerRef.Text = bobj.GetCustomer(selectedValue).Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();`

Comment: Thanks but i cannot see GetCustomer from my PL

Comment: That is why I have written to make `bobj as an instance of DAL instead of BLL`

Comment: I created `DAL.collection dobj = new collection();` and i still cannot see GetCustomer

Comment: I can't help you until I see your solution in LIVE, you need workout this :) .